# Ping Pong in Java Script

Tags: javascript, nan, pong

I'm trying to figure out why `Positions` are returned `NaN` in browser.
this game being rendered in loop and updated as soon as monitor ready to, that's defined in `update()` function an runs infinite.
`reset()` function is a part of updating so it will randomly generate headings, also there is a while which corresponds to filtering little and boring movements.

Positions are consist of

1. A direction which is an Array having x,y times..
2. A Velocity which is constant during the whole game..
3. Differ value constitute of time delta indicates how much
   milliseconds passed from last rendered frame to the new one

I appreciate your help.

```
//br.js

 

     const ausgebur_Velocity = .002
        class Ball {
            constructor(ballElement) {
                this.ballElement = ballElement
                this.reset()
            }
        
            get x() {
                return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElement).getPropertyValue("--x"))
            }
        
            set x(value) {
                this.ballElement.style.setProperty("--x", value)
            }
        
            get y() {
                return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElement).getPropertyValue("--y"))
            }
        
            set y(value) {
                this.ballElement.style.setProperty("--y", value)
            }
        
            reset() {
                this.x = 50;
                this.y = 50;
                this.direction = { x: 50, y: 25 }
        
                while (Math.abs(this.direction.x) <= .2 || Math.abs(this.direction.x >= .9)) {
                    const heading = randomNumberBet(0, 2 * Math.PI)
                    this.direction = { x: Math.cos(heading), y: Math.sin(heading) }
        
                }
                this.velocity = ausgebur_Velocity
            }
        
            update(differ) {
                this.x += this.direction.x * this.velocity * differ;
                this.y += this.direction.y * this.velocity * differ;
                console.log(this.x)
                console.log(this.y)
        
            }
        
        }
        
        function randomNumberBet(min, max) {
            return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
        }
        
        
        // Main Script Below
        const ball = new Ball(document.getElementById('ball'))
        
        let lastTime
        function update(time) {
            if (lastTime != null) {
                const differ = time - lastTime
        
                ball.update()
            }
            lastTime = time
        
            window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
        }
        
        window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
        
         
    //style.css
    
        *,
        *::after,
        *::before {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    :root {
        --hue: 200;
        --saturation: 50%;
        --foreground: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 75%);
        --background: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 25%);
    }
    
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: var(--background)
    }
    
    .control {
        --position: 50;
    
        position: absolute;
        background-color: var(--foreground);
        top: calc(var(--position)*1vh);
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        width: 1vh;
        height: 10vh;
    }
    
    #player_control {
        left: 1vw;
    }
    
    #pc_control {
        right: 1vw;
    }
    
    #ball {
        --x: 50;
        --y: 50;
    
        position: absolute;
        background-color: var(--foreground);
        left: calc(var(--x)*1vh);
        top: calc(var(--y)*1vh);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 3vh;
        height: 3vh;
        border-radius: 50%;
    
    }
    
    .score {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 7vh;
        color: var(--foreground);
    }
    
    .score>* {
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-basis: 0%;
        padding: 0 2vh;
        margin: 1vh 0;
        opacity: .5;
    }
    
    .score>:first-child {
        text-align: right;
        border-right: .5vh solid var(--foreground);
    }

//ping.html

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
        <script src="/br.js" type="module"></script>
        <title>PING</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="score">
            <div class="player_score">0</div>
            <div class="pc_score">0</div>
        </div>
    
        <div id="ball"></div>
        <div class="control" id="player_control"></div>
        <div class="control" id="pc_control"></div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: This seems to be a section of a class, but on itself it is not valid JavaScript. It has unknown variables, like `ausgebur_Velocity` and functions, like `randomNumberBet`, ...and there is no code that is actually calling any of these methods. Please provide a runnable snippet (use toolbar) -- so also include HTML -- that we can run and see the NaN output.  Moreover, with a debugger you should be able to see the source of the NaN. Did you step through the code and inspect variables and expressions?

Comment: you're right I will put more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the the problem is that get the coordonates from `--x` and `--y` css properties, which are not defined here.

Using `top` and `left` works slightly better but I think you'ill have to improve your algorithms.

```js
const ausgebur_Velocity = .002
class Ball {
  constructor(ballElement) {
    this.ballElement = ballElement
    this.reset()
  }

  get x() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElement).getPropertyValue("left"))
  }

  set x(value) {
    this.ballElement.style.setProperty("left", "" + value + "px")
  }

  get y() {
    return parseFloat(getComputedStyle(this.ballElement).getPropertyValue("top"))
  }

  set y(value) {
    this.ballElement.style.setProperty("top", "" + value + "px")
  }

  reset() {
    this.x = 50;
    this.y = 50;
    this.direction = {
      x: 50,
      y: 25
    }

    while (Math.abs(this.direction.x) <= .2 || Math.abs(this.direction.x >= .9)) {
      const heading = randomNumberBet(0, 2 * Math.PI)
      this.direction = {
        x: Math.cos(heading),
        y: Math.sin(heading)
      }

    }
    this.velocity = ausgebur_Velocity
  }

  update(differ) {
    this.x += this.direction.x * this.velocity * differ;
    this.y += this.direction.y * this.velocity * differ;
    console.log("x", this.x)
    console.log("y", this.y)

  }

}

function randomNumberBet(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min
}


// Main Script Below
const ball = new Ball(document.getElementById('ball'))

let lastTime

function update(time) {
  if (lastTime != null) {
    const differ = time - lastTime
    ball.update(differ)
  }
  lastTime = time

  window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 :root {
  --hue: 200;
  --saturation: 50%;
  --foreground: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 75%);
  --background: hsl(var(--hue), var(--saturation), 25%);
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: var(--background)
}

.control {
  --position: 50;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--foreground);
  top: calc(var(--position)*1vh);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 1vh;
  height: 10vh;
}

#player_control {
  left: 1vw;
}

#pc_control {
  right: 1vw;
}

#ball {
  --x: 50;
  --y: 50;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: var(--foreground);
  left: calc(var(--x)*1vh);
  top: calc(var(--y)*1vh);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 3vh;
  height: 3vh;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.score {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 7vh;
  color: var(--foreground);
}

.score>* {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0%;
  padding: 0 2vh;
  margin: 1vh 0;
  opacity: .5;
}

.score>:first-child {
  text-align: right;
  border-right: .5vh solid var(--foreground);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
  <script src="/br.js" type="module"></script>
  <title>PING</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="score">
    <div class="player_score">0</div>
    <div class="pc_score">0</div>
  </div>

  <div id="ball"></div>
  <div class="control" id="player_control"></div>
  <div class="control" id="pc_control"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that is working, however, I couldn't understand the bug why direction won't work.